# Prevent wp_editor to alter initial content

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to load a complete HTML page (including doctype, head and style section)

When I switch to visual tinyMCE removes all "invalid" tags like the body tag, meta tags etc.

It even wraps the title tag into p tags

How can I prevent this?

This is how I insert the wp_editor:

```
wp_editor('', 'my-editor', array('wpautop' => false, 'media_buttons' => false, 'textarea_rows' => 88,'teeny' => true, 'quicktags' => true) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that most rte editor use a contenteditable iframe and the content goes into the body. No browser will allow this, becasue it is not valid html. It gets then kicked out by the browser.